# Is it possible to see the whole REST request body/payload using a filter

Tags: java, rest, filter, jax-rs

I would like to know if there is a way to see the whole body of a REST PUT request using a filter like `com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequestFilter`. This will help us to see the special characters in the request body, which is causing the application to throw bad request code 400.

We tried to use UTF-8 character set and it did not help. Is there a way that we can make allow the special character like ^B and Handle them inside the service.

Answer (score 1):

I always use below method inside myFilter class which implements containerRequestFilter.

This method returns jsonString like {"a":"1","b":"2"}.

```
private String getEntityBody(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) {
  ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  InputStream in = requestContext.getEntityStream();

  String result = null;
  try {
    ReaderWriter.writeTo(in, out);

    byte[] requestEntity = out.toByteArray();
    if (requestEntity.length == 0) {
      result = "";
    } else {
      result = new String(requestEntity, "UTF-8");
    }
    requestContext.setEntityStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(requestEntity));

  } catch (IOException e) {
  }
  return result;
}
```